# How do you prevent an access token from expiring

Tags: micronaut, jwt

I'd like to configure micronaut security so that JWT tokens never expire. I've tried setting the config setting to null as so:

```
 token:
   jwt:
     enabled: true
     signatures:
       generator:
         access-token-expiration: null
```

AND

```
         accessTokenExpiration: null
```

but no luck. It would appear from the code that a null expiration time would always return true:

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/blob/master/security-jwt/src/main/java/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/validator/ExpirationJwtClaimsValidator.java

but this isn't the case. the JWT is still expiring and forcing re-authentication.

has anyone had any success with this?

I've tried setting the access token expiration to null

I expected the token to get validated after an hour, but the server didn't accept the token as validation.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem....

/**
     * Access token expiration. Default value ({@value #DEFAULT_EXPIRATION}).
     * @param accessTokenExpiration The expiration
     */
    public void setAccessTokenExpiration(Integer accessTokenExpiration) {
        if (accessTokenExpiration != null) {
            this.accessTokenExpiration = accessTokenExpiration;
        }
    }

you can't set the access token expiration to null...

Answer (score 0):

As this property is deprecated the I would recommenced using  `micronaut.security.token.jwt.generator.access-token.expiration`

86400 - second in 1 day
If you wish token to never expire just put a big enough number of seconds.

`micronaut.security.token.jwt.generator.access-token.expiration=86400 * days`